# Complex object Header Binding issue in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Sounds a lot like other questions about binding headers - but generally they are about simplistic headers like TextBoxes....

My headers need to use an object instantiation that has an several image and text components in it, called EMSPlanViewDeviceNew. This has a DP called TheDeviceProperty which holds all the data for a device.

This is how I setup my column header

```
DataGridTemplateColumn  TextColumn2 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
FrameworkElementFactory TextBorder2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(EMSTextCell));
FrameworkElementFactory TextBlock2  = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

ImageTemplate              = new DataTemplate();
TextColumn2.CellTemplate   = ImageTemplate;

// Setup a Header Template to use for the backup paths column
System.Windows.DataTemplate BackupHeaderTemplate  = new System.Windows.DataTemplate();
Binding HeaderBinding        = new Binding("BackupPaths[" + index.ToString() + "].BackupDevice");

FrameworkElementFactory MVDeviceColumnHeader = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(EMSPlanViewDeviceNew));
MVDeviceColumnHeader.SetValue(EMSPlanViewDeviceNew.HeightProperty, (double)60);
MVDeviceColumnHeader.SetValue(EMSPlanViewDeviceNew.WidthProperty, (double)85);
MVDeviceColumnHeader.SetValue(EMSPlanViewDeviceNew.TheDeviceProperty, HeaderBinding);

BackupHeaderTemplate.VisualTree = MVDeviceColumnHeader;

TextColumn2.HeaderTemplate = BackupHeaderTemplate;
```

The Dataset holds a list of BackupPaths with properties BackupDevice, BackupStatus and BackupLevel. At runtime, the grid is populated and the header objects are drawn, but the header object is not shown with the correct data, just the defaults, so that tells me that the binding is not connecting to the dataset properly, or it is but in such a way that the "UpdateVisuals" method in the object doesn't get called so the header is not redrawn with the correct data.
Solutions I've seen here suggest using a HeaderTemplate, but I think I'm doing that so I'm not sure what else to try to get it to fire the binding.

This is what it looks like at runtime
[image: Header Row with two populated rows]

The header row objects should look the same as the first column images.

Can anyone suggest what else I need to do to correct my error here. Thanks.

```
public class BackupDataSet
```

{
    private string _TheAddress;
    public string  TheAddress
    {
        get { return _TheAddress; }
        set { _TheAddress = value; }
    }

```
private EMSDevices.EMSBasicDevice _TheDevice;
public EMSDevices.EMSBasicDevice TheDevice
{
    get { return _TheDevice; }
    set { _TheDevice = value; }
}

private BitmapImage _DeviceIcon;
public BitmapImage  DeviceIcon
{
    get { return _DeviceIcon; }
    set { _DeviceIcon = value; }
}

private string _TheIdent;
public string  TheIdent
{
    get { return _TheIdent; }
    set { _TheIdent = value; }
}

private string _TheMainSignalPath;
public string  TheMainSignalPath
{
    get { return _TheMainSignalPath; }
    set { _TheMainSignalPath = value; }
}

public string BackupPathsCount
{
    get
    {
        if (CountGoodBackupPaths() > 0)
            return CountGoodBackupPaths().ToString();
        else if (CountLowBackupPaths() > 0)
            return (-1 * CountLowBackupPaths()).ToString();
        else
            return "--";
    }
}

private List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath> _BackupPaths;
public List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath>  BackupPaths
{
    get { return _BackupPaths; }
    set { _BackupPaths = value; }
}

public void AddBackupPath(EMSDevices.EMSBasicDevice backupDevice, EMSDevices.SignalSetting backupStatus, int backupLevel)
{
    EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath NewBackupPath = new EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath(backupDevice, backupStatus, backupLevel);

    _BackupPaths.Add(NewBackupPath);
}

public BackupDataSet(string address, BitmapImage icon, string ident, string mainsignalpath)
{
    _TheAddress        = address;
    _DeviceIcon        = icon;
    _TheIdent          = ident;
    _TheMainSignalPath = mainsignalpath;

    _BackupPaths       = new List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath>();
}

public BackupDataSet(EMSDevices.EMSBasicDevice device)
{
    _TheAddress        = device.TheAddress;
    _TheDevice         = device.Clone();
    _TheMainSignalPath = device.TheMainSignalPath;

    _BackupPaths       = new List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath>();
}

public int CountGoodBackupPaths()
{
    List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath> Paths = new List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath>();

    Paths = (from BackupPath in _BackupPaths
                where BackupPath.BackupStatus == EMSDevices.SignalSetting.GoodSignal
                select BackupPath).ToList();

    return Paths.Count;
}

public int CountLowBackupPaths()
{
    List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath> Paths = new List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath>();

    Paths = (from BackupPath in _BackupPaths
                where BackupPath.BackupStatus == EMSDevices.SignalSetting.LowSignal
                select BackupPath).ToList();

    return Paths.Count;
}
```

}

This is how the dataset is populated:

```
if (AllCIEDevices.Count > 0)
```

{
    CIEDataSet = new List();

```
foreach(EMSDevices.EMSBasicDevice dev1 in AllCIEDevices)
{
    BackupDataSet dataset = new BackupDataSet(dev1);

    foreach(EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath backup in dev1.BackupPaths)
    {
        dataset.AddBackupPath(backup.BackupDevice, backup.BackupStatus, backup.BackupLevel);
    }
    CIEDataSet.Add(dataset);
}
// Setup the grid for devices that have the CIE as the parent
PanelDeviceView.ItemsSource   = CIEDataSet; 
SetupDataGrid(PanelDeviceView, Headers);
```

}

So the DataGrid already has the dataset connected to it via the PanelDeviceView.ItemSource.

Each Row of data has a device, some other parameters and a list of BackupPaths.

Comment: Where is the BackupPaths property defined?

Comment: BackupPaths is a property of a class called BackupDataSet:

Comment: And how and where is this class used?

Comment: private List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath> _BackupPaths;
public List<EMSDevices.EMSBackupPath>  BackupPaths
{
    get { return _BackupPaths; }
    set { _BackupPaths = value; }
}

Comment: Anybody any ideas here? Or is this one a dead-duck and I need to find another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the BackupPaths property defined in the same class where you create the template and the columns?

Comment: Yes it is. However, BackupPaths is a List of type EMSBackupPath which is not defined in the same class, it is defined elsewhere. But, there is no reason why I can't move the definition to be in the same class as it is used nowhere else but in this class.

Comment: Hmmm...actually, no it's not..... BackupPaths is a list of type EMSBackupPath that is a property of each Device, so it is defined  in the Device class.

Comment: I've now moved the definition of BackupPaths and the BackupDataSet to be in the same class as the class that displays the DataGrid. Sadly this has not helped at all - the problem reduces to the binding not being triggered when the BackupDevice is bound to the DeviceProperty (a DP not a normal property) when the grid is populated. The trigger must occur for the device value to be correctly set in the device icon. The binding works at the row level, but not at the header level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Source` property of the `Binding` to the object where the `BackupPaths` property is defined:

```
Binding HeaderBinding = new Binding("BackupPaths[" + index.ToString() + "].BackupDevice") { Source = this };
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion..... unfortunately it does not work.  The column data uses the same technique to access the data to display, so the data cells are correctly populated....but the header not. I'm now wondering if the problem isn't related to the fact that each row data (an entry in the dataset attached to the grid) essentially duplicates the header data, and maybe that is confounding the process. Maybe I need to pass the header data separately from the dataset, and manually bind to that so it only gets one copy of header variables, and not one per row (if that makes any sense!)

Comment: This seems to be a dead duck after all.... perhaps it really just can't be done, or at least, can't be done by anyone on this forum....

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I believe that the solution is to be found by not trying to bind the header to an object in the main data context but to a separate object array that only contains headers. The reason for my thinking is that as each row is filled it would provide another data set for the header, which isn't what is needed as there is only one header row, for all the data rows. As before, that row data is correctly bound, but the header row is not. I'll get back when I've tried my idea out!

Comment: You can bind to any object you want. Just make sure that you set the Source property of the binding to this object like I did in my answer.

Comment: Indeed.... however which "object" is the "this"? The DataGrid, the data source, the row of data? To my understanding, using "this" refers to the container object, i.e. the class (in my case) EMS_BackupPathControl, which has a DataGrid in it, which has its datasource set to a List of BackupDataSets, each one of which contains data for each possible backup path... (Yes, it is complicated!). So it's a bit difficult to know which the "this" needs to be, but I'd guess it is the dataset, or maybe the datagrid? So how to specify that in the "Source" statement???

Comment: I have established that "this" instantiates to the container class (a  EMS_BackupPathControl), so the challenge is to set the source to either the dataset connected to the datagrid, or in my modified version, a separate data list of "Headers" which is passed to the Setup method as a parameter. (I'm pretty sure "this" won't be the right source object in this case.)

Comment: Ok.....Success at last!    This is the line that fixed it:                           Binding HeaderBinding      = new Binding("BackupPaths[" + index.ToString() + "].BackupDevice") {Source = TheDataGrid.ItemsSource}; What is basically does it tells the binding that it must find the data in ItemsSource of the Datagrid, which is where I put the data in the first place! Thanks to mm8 for input that (eventually) pointed me in the correct direction !